# Can we list more blog posts per page?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, blog

I love [**the new blog format**](http://blog.stackexchange.com), but paging back to find an older blog post is somewhat arduous — there are only five short excerpts per page.

Instead of scrolling down a short ways to click 'older', scroll, older, scroll, older… can we see more blog posts per page?

There's really not all that much content on each page; I'm sure the vast majority of users have enough bandwidth to see more than just those few excerpts per page. Can we up that to about 20?

Comment: Up to 20? You mean, with the ability to choose, like it is possible to list 15/30/50 questions per page?

Comment: Agreed - going to increase the post number and adding a few more navigation options to make finding posts easier. Some pending fixes going into pagination that I'm waiting on before going to production.

Comment: @Jon almost three years later, any update?

Answer (score 4):

I agree, a link to "older posts" isn't a good way to browse a blog, especially having to `click/scroll/click/scroll/etc` just to get back to where you were reading previously.

The *tags* work well, but perhaps in addition to those and more posts per page, have a *calender* in the side bar.
with all blog posts being a link in the calender for date posted.