# Add a calender to the new blog for navigating to posts based on date; And specific area being viewed

Tags: feature-request, blog

There have been a few questions asked recently about improving blog navigation.

The main two which support my feature-request are:
[Can we list more blog posts per page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259936/can-we-list-more-blog-posts-per-page)
[Show authors blog posts in reverse chronological order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261253/show-authors-blog-posts-in-reverse-chronological-order)

In the "More posts per page" question, [I suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259939/230506) using a calender to be able to select blog posts based on day/month etc.

Perhaps the idea of the calender could be extended, and changed to allow selecting blog posts based on the area you are viewing.

---

### The calender

Consider a basic web calender, e.g.  shows all days of the month in a grid, and months and years changeable with arrows above the day grid.
The days in the grid are highlighted and click-able when a blog posts exists for that date.

If more than one blog post exists for a date, then clicking will take user to a page showing all posts from that date.
The page showing multiple posts can either have:

1. Full articles on that page (paginated if required)
2. Or as a list of excerpts/post summaries (paginated if required) with
   excerpt being click-able to go to a page showing the full article

[image: basic-web/blog-calender]

---

### Options

- When viewing main blog homepage, or specifically not in any specific
  area, the calender will show days/months/years and the click-able
  days in the grid will link to *all posts* throughout the blog based on their *post date*.
- When viewing a specific area, such as /authors ([for
  example](http://blog.stackexchange.com/authors/spolsky/)) the
  calender could change to show all posts by that author, again with
  click-able days to other posts by that author.
- Specific areas can be added as useful, for example when viewing a
  specific tag, the calender will have click-able days for all posts
  from the tag you are viewing.

Comment: +1 nice suggestion. There is plenty of room in right side panel on the main bog homepage.